# DbArithmeticExpression arguments must have a numeric common type. Entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, datetime

I have One MVC Application, In that I want to grab record from sql server database as per my requirement. Mainly I have Table "OfficeDetail" in that One column is "ApprovedDate" and Second is "ChildCount". "Approvedate" contain a date of when user's document was approved. Second "ChildCount" contain Integer Value. I also searched another question on this site,but didnt get solution. I am using two where conditions, So for get record i written this code.

```
 public IEnumerable<EmployeeModel> GetAllExpired()
    {
        DateTime my = DateTime.Today;

        DBContext = new ConsumerNomineeFormEntities();
        return (from f in DBContext.OfficeDetails

               where (SqlFunctions.DateDiff("second",f.Date,my.Date)>90)
               where (f.ChildCount>5)
                select new EmployeeModel
                    {
                        XConsumer_Id = f.ConsumerNo_,
                        XApproved = f.Date,
                        XChildCount = f.ChildCount,
                        XTimeSpent = (f.Date - DateTime.Today).TotalDays
                    }).ToList();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be the computation of XTimeSpent as you need to use sqlfunctions to subtract dates

Comment: thnx.. But till i have one problem As per my where condition I have one recor in table which have approved date is 2015-08-20 and childcount is 3 , Therefore the difference between this date and todays date is more than 90 days. But no any record on my screen while i have one record

Comment: Ok, but why don't you mark this answer as solved? Your problem description was about the exception and it was solved with this answer..

Comment: Because your answer is not perfect solution... but I am giving your credits... and what about mine...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, finally i got , I have to make changes like this ,

```
DBContext = new ConsumerNomineeFormEntities();
        return (from f in DBContext.OfficeDetails
                where SqlFunctions.DateDiff("day", f.Date, my.Date) > 90
                where f.ChildCount < 5
                select new EmployeeModel
                    {
                        XConsumer_Id = f.ConsumerNo_,
                        XApproved = f.Date,
                        XChildCount = f.ChildCount,
                        XTimeSpent = SqlFunctions.DateDiff("day", f.Date, my.Date)
                    }).ToList();
```